# How can I use one asp.net tempDirectory of precomiled files for multiple IIS servers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have enabled shared configuration option on IIS servers as I have multiple web servers.
In web.config file I have defined tempDirectory attribute, which points to shared network location, so that multiple web servers can use the same precompiled files.

Once I browse the web site, on one of the web servers the pool is initializing and everything is fine, but once the request go through the rest web servers, application pools can't load some assemblies, as they are already loaded in another app domain. Here is the message that I receive:

```
The assembly '\\561217-Fileclus\ASP.NET Temp Folder\root\7788e585\8a96dd12\App_Code.dll' is already loaded in another appdomain. Setting <deployment retail="true" /> in machine.config can help solve this issue.
```

Setting for deployment tag retail attribute to true doesn't help.

I'm running web site and not web application and this should be so.

Here is the version information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055

Comment: I'm assuming you are run-time compiling.  Why not [precompile and deploy without all the complex overhead](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm making changes on the web site every day, both in App_Code folder class files and aspx.cs or ascx.cs files, that's why I have web site on production instead of web application. If I precompile the web site and put it on the prod as you suggest, then it means that once I make some change in the .cs file I need each time put assemblies on the production environment, which will cause a problem.

Comment: Sounds like you have a deployment problem and not a development problem :(

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is no development problem, it's a configuration problem of the web servers(